# is xfs only available on a 64bit OS?

Tags: linux

I have installed xfs on linux ubuntu, x86 32bit

and I realized that xfs is 64bit file system?

Is it compatible?

Or do I have to install a different file system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) is perfectly usable on 32-bit Linux systems, although a few additional limits are placed on the sizes of files and the filesystem itself. You should also have no issues moving that filesystem to a 64-bit host, as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/q/201267/60384) the filesystem layout is the same. Therefore, the fact that you have a 32-bit host is not an issue.

Whether you should use XFS at all, though, is a very controversial issue I'd rather not get into :-)